# Python: How do i convert date and time (in 1 string) into a timestamp

Tags: python, timestamp

Using Python3:

How do I convert the below string to a datetime in milliseconds.

2018-10-20T18:31:20.318000 -to-> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx which is some number which represents the datetime in milliseconds

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime()`

```py
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.to_datetime('2018-10-20T18:31:20.318000').timestamp()
print(ts)
```

```
1540060280.318
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `parse`

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

s="2018-10-20T18:31:20.318000"

print(parse(s).timestamp())
```

Output:

```
1540049480.318
```